# ckfinder unable to find image manipulation component

Tags: ckfinder

Any help appreciated.
We have moved several sites from one server to another. They all work except one. When you goto a page and click the image button then the browse button you get the error 'Unable to find image manipulation component'. I have checked all the permissions agains the other sites as well as the user files directory. We are running CKFinder 2.0.2 on Windows IIS 7 using ASP.
The original developer is no longer available so we are working a little blind.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP/Configuration/Images#Scaling. Most likely your server is missing some older ASP.NET. Please try installing it and setting the component to Asp.Net.